# DFP "Serve ads in a non-JavaScript environment"

Tags: adsense, google-dfp

I read the guide at: http://support.google.com/dfp_premium/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1638620
but i can't implement it.

I tried with this src for an image, but I see blank page: http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ad?iu=/4767628/TomsBlog_Home_ATF_300x250&sz=300x250&c=1803379939

Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The blank page seems to be an incompatibility between DFP and Outlook combined with a non-IE default browser.

Having implemented an email campaign and received an email carrying an ad into Outlook, the click-throughs work when I set my default browser to IE but not if I have it set to Chrome.

This post suggests it has something to do with cookies: [Google DFP ads in email behaving strangely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697866/google-dfp-ads-in-email-behaving-strangely)

Update: the issue I saw yesterday (ad link in email goes to blank page when using Outlook + non-IE) has gone away. Not sure if it was a temporary outage or if it's an intermittent problem)

Comment: It is intermittent and also depends on c parameter value. For some values it works consistently. For some it works in Chrome, but fails in IE, for some it failed in IE, but after opening in Chrome, it started to work in IE as well.