# How can I serve ads in an email newsletter via Double-Click for Publishers?

Tags: html-email, advertisement-server, double-click-advertising

I'm serving ads via Double-Click for Publishers Small Business, and wish to include the ad in an HTML newsletter. DfP's support site [says](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1258792?hl=en) "ad serving to newsletters is not officially supported by DoubleClick".

How can I get DfP to work within an email newsletter?

A complication is that users may be using an ad blocker, which would allow the ad to display within their email client, but wouldn't allow the user to click through to the ad.

Comment: How is this off-topic? It's saying, "Here's a challenge; how do I do it?". There are a small number of specific, technical ways to do this--it's not just asking general opinions or recommendations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using DfP with the approach suggested at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16764513/906814

> Had the same problem and I solved it by using script to redirect click
>   via script on my web server where ad is shown again so that all the
>   cookies can be set.

This may fail if the user is running AdBlock, so I added the checks detailed at http://thepcspy.com/read/how_to_block_adblock to display an error message when that occurs.

Comment: I'm looking at this problem for the first time just this week, and don't fully understand it yet, but I've heard rumors that Google is making changes that would make this no longer work, in the coming months... ?